# Python equivalent of JS path.resolve()?

Tags: javascript, python

I want to do some path resolution in python without assuming file separator char. In JS you use `path.resolve(__dirname, '..','xxx','yyy')` to get `$PWD/../xxx/yyy` on *nix machines. Is there an equivalent function in python?

Comment: `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'foo', 'bar')`

Comment: Note that Node.js’s `__dirname` is the directory containing the running module, not necessarily the working directory. `os.getcwd()` is the working directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As James Smith pointed out, you can use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) function.

```py
import os

os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '..', 'xxx', 'yyy') # Returns $PWD/../xxx/yyy
```

It joins one or more path components using the platform specific directory separator. Could be used for both relative and absolute paths.

```
os.path.join('foo', 'bar') # Returns foo/bar
```